# Mathematical approaches to analysis of terraforming

Tags: planetary-science, terraforming

The process of terraforming has been discussed at length in this site. I am wondering if there has been any mathematical analysis of how terraforming would take place in credible scientific publications or authoritative blogs.

I'm particularly interested in a set of equations that would in a very basic way address a controlled terraforming process in a defined time-span. The scenario would not need to be realistic based on today's technology, I'm interested in how the evolution would be addressed mathematically.

Comment: I'm debating answer/comment on this. I do not believe it can be summed to a set of equations, period. It's too broad of a topic, too large of a system. But I might recommend some speculative fiction on the topic, which I think may be the best you get today.

Comment: Hi @YigitTurgut and Welcome to Space! This is an interesting question. I made some adjustments to the wording to help it fit into the way this site tends to run. Feel free to adjust the language further.

Comment: @Saiboogu it's always dangerous to say "nobody knows the answer to your question" or "nobody has ever tried this" unless you are an active and well-read expert. The question is more "has someone tried this" than "would you believe their results". While everybody uses supercomputer models for planetary systems now, people really did try to express things as sets of differential equations, and try to solve them analytically in the past.

Comment: @uhoh I even meant to throw in a 'I am not an expert on this, however' disclaimer. I guess I just fear, on some level, 'there's an equation for it' is an overused trope in fiction, leading folks to perhaps believe really complex systems can always be reduced down to a handy formula. I'm not familiar with the past work you mention, so I'll just observe with interest to see if this question produces some informative responses.

Comment: @Saiboogu now you've got me thinking... [Has stellar evolution ever been modeled analytically?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29743/7982)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at global climate change modeling as a basis for understanding terraforming.  Particularly, look into Sandia National Laboratory’s Energy Exascale Earth System Model (E3SM) project.  It’s probably the most advanced model of its kind, but may be more than you need at this time.  Introduce a few controls inputs (e.g. greenhouse gas concentration, etc...), and a target endstate (e.g. for chemical/thermal distribution in the model) and you’ve basically got yourself an optimal control problem in which can then be discretized and solved by a myriad of methods.  Of course, this would most likely be a pde-constrained optimization problem which probably doesn’t have a closed form analytical solution.